How to use EventEmitter with discord.js
I have a typescript app that I am writing and would like to add discord embeds to. However, I am having an issue adding the discord.js module to it because it is not allowing me to call this.emit or call myClass.on with the class that extends from EventEmitter.
Here is my Listeners class extending EventEmitter.
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

export class Listeners extends EventEmitter {
    private subscriptions: number[] = [];

    constructor() {
        super(); // Call the parent class constructor
    }

    public async start() {
        const mySub = await this.subscribe('test');
        this.subscriptions.push(mySub);
    }

    private async subscribe(msg: string): Promise<number> {
        this.emit('market', msg);
        return Promise.resolve(1);
    }
}

Here is my index.ts:
import { Listeners } from './listeners';

const runListener = async () => {
    const listeners = new Listeners(connection);
    await listeners.start();

    listeners.on('message', (msg: string) => {
        // do something here...
    });
}

runListener();

As soon as I npm install discord.js I get the following errors:
Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Listeners'. Did you mean to access the static member 'Listeners.on' instead?

and
Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'Listeners'.ts(2339)

I tried looking around, but I havent found anything as to why. I would assume that it has something to do with the discord.js module also using EventEmitters? Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Let's try import { EventEmitter } from 'node:events'; instead.

First of all, just a heads up, you are not listening to your emitted 'market' event. Try this:
listeners.on('market', (msg: string) => {
        // do something here...
    });

Secondly, you passed connection in your instantiation - const listeners = new Listeners(connection);. If it is needed, ensure you pass it properly:
    constructor(private connection: any) {
        super();
    }

Regarding the errors, try changing your tsconfig.json to have something like this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true // ignore type checking, may resolve conflict
  }
}

